# How to know mouseLeave on two element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

Im trying to create a drop down menu when hovering, something like the the following.

Under the header of a website.

[image]

Im doing so with jQuery, Im using the events mouseEnter and mouse leave.
with the following code.

```
 var LastThis = null;
                $(".divOpener, #floatingNewNav")
                .mouseleave(function(event)
                {
                    console.log(event);
                    if($(event.toElement).attr("id") != "floatingNewNav") // do not close since we leaved the element but we got on the floating nav.
                    {
                        $("#floatingNewNav").hide(0);

                        if(LastThis.attr("id") == "ShopByBrand")
                        {
                            LastThis.removeClass("NavSelected");
                            $("#"+LastThis.attr("id")+"_Nav").css("display","none");
                        }
                        if(LastThis.attr("id") == "ShopByCategory")
                        {
                            LastThis.removeClass("NavSelected");
                            $("#"+LastThis.attr("id")+"_Nav").css("display","none");
                        }
                        if(LastThis.attr("id") == "ShopByPrice")
                        {
                            LastThis.removeClass("NavSelected");
                            $("#"+LastThis.attr("id")+"_Nav").css("display","none");
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(".divOpener")
                .mouseenter(function()
                {
                    LastThis = $(this);
                    if($(this).attr("id") == "ShopByBrand")
                    {
                        $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_Nav").css("display","block");
                        $(this).addClass('NavSelected');
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("id") == "ShopByCategory")
                    {
                        $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_Nav").css("display","block");
                        $(this).addClass('NavSelected');
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("id") == "ShopByPrice")
                    {
                        $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_Nav").css("display","block");
                        $(this).addClass('NavSelected');
                    }
                    var DivPosition = $(this).parent().position();
                    var Position = $(this).position();

                    var curTop = DivPosition.top;
                    var curLeft = Position.left;
                    var curWidth = $(this).width();
                    var curHeight = $(this).parent().height();
                    var DivWidth = $(this).parent().width();

                    var WidthOfNav = 400;

                    var OffSetLeft = (curLeft+(curWidth/2)-(WidthOfNav/2)+WidthOfNav)-(DivPosition.left+DivWidth);
                    var OffSetLeft = (OffSetLeft>0?OffSetLeft:0);

                    $("#floatingNewNav").css("position","absolute");
                    $("#floatingNewNav").css("height","100px");
                    $("#floatingNewNav").css("top",(curTop+curHeight)+"px");
                    $("#floatingNewNav").css("left",((curLeft+(curWidth/2))-(WidthOfNav/2))-OffSetLeft+"px");
                    $("#floatingNewNav").css("width",WidthOfNav+"px");

                    $("#floatingNewNav").show(0);
                });
```

Html

```
 <div id="newNavDiv">
                        <span><form style="display: inline-block;" action="search.php" method="get"><input id="SearchBar" name="q" type="text"></form></span>
                        <div class="SearchButtonDiv"><input id="SearchButton" type="button" value="SEARCH"></div>
                <span class="NewNavSeparator"></span>
                <div id="Special" style="color: red;">
                    SPECIALS
                </div>
                <span class="NewNavSeparator"></span>
                <div id="ShopByBrand" class="divOpener">
                    SHOP BY<br/>BRAND
                </div>
                <span class="NewNavSeparator"></span>
                <div id="ShopByCategory" class="divOpener">
                    SHOP BY<br/>CATEGORY
                </div>
                <span class="NewNavSeparator"></span>
                <div id="ShopByPrice" class="divOpener">
                    SHOP BY<br/>PRICE
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="floatingNewNav">
                <div id="ShopByBrand_Nav"></div>
                <div id="ShopByCategory_Nav"></div>
                <div id="ShopByPrice_Nav"></div>
            </div>
```

css

```
#WebsiteHeader
        {
            height: 170px;
            background: url("Photo/header.png") no-repeat top;
            background-size:100%;
        }
        #NewNavBar
        {
            height: 42px;
            background: url("Photo/newNavigator.png") no-repeat top;
            background-size:100%;

            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #newNavDiv
        {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 960px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        #SearchBar
        {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: grey;

            width: 245px;
            height: 24px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            background-color: #ffffff;

            border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
        }
        .SearchButtonDiv
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #SearchButton
        {
            color:#ffffff;
            font-size: 13px;

            height: 30px;
            background-color: red;

            padding: 8px;

            border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            border: 0px solid;
        }
        #Special
        {
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 130px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;

            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: "Arial";/* for firefox*/
            font-family: "Arial Black";/* if browser have the font it will overide arial*/
            font-weight:900;/* for firefox*/
            font-size: 13px;
            font-style: italic;
        }
        .divOpener
        {
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 140px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;

            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: "Arial";/* for firefox*/
            font-family: "Arial Black";/* if browser have the font it will overide arial*/
            font-weight:900;/* for firefox*/
            font-size: 13px;
            font-style: italic;
        }
        .NewNavSeparator
        {
            border-right: 1px rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.70) solid;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-left: 6px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        #MainPagesLinks
        {
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }
        #MainPagesLinks a
        {
            text-align: center;
            color:#ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;

            font-size: 13px;

            width: 75px;

            display: inline-block;
            background-color: red;

            padding-left: 4px;
            padding-right: 4px;

            border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;


            border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,240,240,0.4);
            border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,240,240,0.4);
            border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,240,240,0.4);
            box-shadow:
                inset 0 3px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.22),
                inset 0 20px 10px rgba(255,255,255,.12),
                0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
                0 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

            /*border: 1px solid #000000;*/
        }
        #floatingNewNav
        {
            background-color: #aaaac6;
            margin-top: 0px;

            border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
        }
        .NavSelected
        {
            color:black;
            background-color: #aaaac6;
            border-bottom: 0px #aaaac6 solid;

            border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
        }
```

.divOpener class is the `<a> Shop by category</a>` and others links
`#floatingNewNav`

Here is the live example.
https://www.newyorkpowertools.com/Template/headerTemplate.html

You will see in that example that it works in chrome,Ie,safari  But on **firefox** it doesn't work. beacause for some reason firefox dont return the object `toElement` in the `event` object..

## My question

Is there a way I could create an event mouseEnter and mouseLeave with two element and fake that it is ONLY one element so I dont need to

`if($(event.toElement).attr("id") != "floatingNewNav")`

Thanks for the help, And Sorry for the confusing question,.

Comment: it seems your if statements are unnecessary since you only have 3 menu items and in each if you are doing the exact same thing. EDIT: sorry didn't see the floatingdiv, just check for not floatingdiv

Comment: It is nessary since if i remove it as soon as i exit the .DivOpener every thing close even if I go over the floating nav.

Comment: Yea see my edit, just check id for 'not floating nav' instead of checking for all 3 ids. Or you can use https://api.jquery.com/not/ or you can check if $(this) hasClass divOpener or not, lots of ways to do it in one check instead of 3

Comment: Could you add the css so I can put this in a fiddle to see how it is interacting

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aheLv/

Comment: Im sorry I might sound stupid. What in the jsfiddle do you want to show me as I don't see the difference :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this http://jsfiddle.net/aheLv/1/

```
$(".divOpener, #floatingNewNav").mouseenter(function () {
    if (!$(this).is('#floatingNewNav')) {
        LastThis = $(this);
    }
    $("#" + LastThis.attr("id") + "_Nav").css("display", "block");
    LastThis.addClass('NavSelected');

    var DivPosition = LastThis.parent().position();
    var Position = LastThis.position();

    var curTop = DivPosition.top;
    var curLeft = Position.left;
    var curWidth = LastThis.width();
    var curHeight = LastThis.parent().height();
    var DivWidth = LastThis.parent().width();

    var WidthOfNav = 400;

    var OffSetLeft = (curLeft + (curWidth / 2) - (WidthOfNav / 2) + WidthOfNav) - (DivPosition.left + DivWidth);
    var OffSetLeft = (OffSetLeft > 0 ? OffSetLeft : 0);

    $("#floatingNewNav").css("position", "absolute");
    $("#floatingNewNav").css("height", "100px");
    $("#floatingNewNav").css("top", (curTop + curHeight) + "px");
    $("#floatingNewNav").css("left", ((curLeft + (curWidth / 2)) - (WidthOfNav / 2)) - OffSetLeft + "px");
    $("#floatingNewNav").css("width", WidthOfNav + "px");

    $("#floatingNewNav").show(0);
});
```

There are lot of things you can do to refactor this code. Actually there are some extra stuff in the fiddle that I am taking them out now, I will update soon

UPDATE:

here is the final code

```
var LastThis = null;
var openers = $(".divOpener, #floatingNewNav");

openers.mouseleave(function (event) {
    $("#floatingNewNav").hide();
    LastThis.removeClass("NavSelected");
    $("#" + LastThis.attr("id") + "_Nav").hide();
});

openers.mouseenter(function () {
    if (!$(this).is('#floatingNewNav')) {
        LastThis = $(this);
    }
    $("#" + LastThis.attr("id") + "_Nav").show();
    LastThis.addClass('NavSelected');

    var DivPosition = LastThis.parent().position();
    var Position = LastThis.position();

    var curTop = DivPosition.top;
    var curLeft = Position.left;
    var curWidth = LastThis.width();
    var curHeight = LastThis.parent().height();
    var DivWidth = LastThis.parent().width();

    var WidthOfNav = 400;

    var OffSetLeft = (curLeft + (curWidth / 2) - (WidthOfNav / 2) + WidthOfNav) - (DivPosition.left + DivWidth);
    var OffSetLeft = (OffSetLeft > 0 ? OffSetLeft : 0);

    $("#floatingNewNav").css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'height': '100px',
        'top': (curTop + curHeight) + 'px',
        'left': ((curLeft + (curWidth / 2)) - (WidthOfNav / 2)) - OffSetLeft + 'px',
        'width': WidthOfNav + 'px'
    }).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aheLv/2/

As a suggestion, menus like these can be done in css only if you structure your html the right way. See Kevin's answer for the structure

Comment: Wow. It is working!   Il wait for you reply Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

To create a drop-down menu that appears on hover, like the one in your example, I would use CSS. See example below:

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Im not exsactly sure this could fit my need, as I think that elements will get pushed down on hover of menu.

Comment: If you use `position: absolute;` on the `.sub-menu` and `position: relative;` on the `li` container, it shouldn't push down the other elements on hover.

Comment: I should clarify, you have to write additional CSS beyond my example to get the menu to be styled and positioned like your screenshot. My example only illustrates the show/hide functionality of your desired on-hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw out a different concept, your picture screams "jQuery tabs" :-), so I used simple tabs, and created a jQuery trigger event for each one.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/Ay665/1/)

JS

```
$('.charts').tabs();

$('#firstone').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).trigger('click');
});
$('#secondone').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).trigger('click');
});
$('#thirdone').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Not elegant, but I'll play with it some more and see if it can be 'elegantized'.

Comment: Hum that is a nice idea. Il try to make it look like the nav I want.

but it will have to be able to close when mouse is not there anymore and also it has to float over the website content. :S

Comment: I was actually able to get the tabs to work like a nav bar (panels popup on a command, but tabs stay visible), but unfortunately, it doesn't overlay the elements below it, it pushes them down.  Oh well...just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're overcomplicating things..

How about just tracking the direction of the mouse, and if its headed downward, don't hide the menuitems below..

Check this fiddle..
http://jsfiddle.net/ReVLN/2/

Checked its working in Mozilla and chrome/etc..

```
 var mY = 0;
$('div.menuItems').mousemove(function(e){
// moving upward
if (e.pageY < mY) {
    flag = "upward";
} else {
    flag = "downward";
}
// set new mY after doing test above
mY = e.pageY;
});
```

Thanks,
jf_it